# Doctrine (postgresql) Pessimistic Locking - doesn't throw PessimisticLockException

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine2

Пытаюсь зазюзать Pessimistic Locking with Doctrine ORM for PostgreSql. Doctrine и PostgreSql с дефолтной конфигурацией.

Пример кода (Symfony Command).

`$sleep` - время ождиания в секундах

```
$manager = $this->getContainer()->get('mmi.manager.message');
$conn = $manager->em()->getConnection();

$manager->em()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
try {
    $entity = $manager->repo()->find('cd7eb9e9', LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

    $entity->setState(EntityActionInterface::STATE_IN_PROGRESS);
    $manager->em()->persist($entity);
    $manager->em()->flush();

    $ts = (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    $output->writeln("TS: {$ts}");

    if ($sleep) {
        $output->writeln("Sleep: {$sleep}");
        sleep($sleep);
    }

    $entity->setMessage([$ts]);
    $manager->em()->persist($entity);
    $manager->em()->flush();

    $conn->commit();
} catch (PessimisticLockException $ex) {
    var_dump(get_class($ex));

    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $ex;
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    var_dump(get_class($ex));

    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $ex;
}
```

**How tested**

Запускаю 2 команды. Первая стартуте и ждет 20 секунд. Вторая стартуте без ожидания.

**Expected result**

Вторая команда выбрасывает исключение `PessimisticLockException`

**Actual result**

Вторая команда ждет пока не закоммитится транзакция из первой команды и потом обюновляет запись.

**Question**

Как заставить доктирну выплюнуть `PessimisticLockException` если полученная запись залочена?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос подробно описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586294/doctrine-postgresql-pessimistic-locking-doesnt-throw-pessimisticlockexcepti)

Вся суть в том, что я неправильно понял блокировки. По сслыке есть описание того как я решил проблему в моем случае.